# Azure AppService query.fetchLimit it doesn't work

Tags: azure, mobile-application, xcode9, swift4, azure-web-app-service

Azureservice taking data from the data when it is being reduced to 50. Could be downloaded 1,000 previously. How Can I fix this.

Code:

```
fileprivate func loadDataRecursiveForQuery(_ query: MSQuery, success: @escaping () -> Void, unsuccess: @escaping () -> Void){
    query.fetchLimit = 1000 // it doesn't work!
    query.includeTotalCount = true
    query.fetchOffset = GlobalVariables.result.count
    query.read { ( result, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("ERROR ", err.localizedDescription)
            unsuccess()
            return
        } else if let items = result?.items {
            GlobalVariables.result.addObjects(from: items)

            if result!.totalCount > GlobalVariables.result.count{
                self.loadDataRecursiveForQuery(query, success: {
                    success()
                }, unsuccess: {
                    unsuccess()
                })
            }
            else{
                success()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

App services download limit "app.js" by modifying your file, you can specify. File path:

> YourWebSite.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/app.js

New Azure Service "AppServiceEditor" allows to make this process easier.
[image]

"PageSize: 1000" code define variable at azureMobileApps
[image]